# Is volatile functionality same with synchronized getter?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following:

```
private int i;

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public synchronized int getISync() {
    return i;
}
```

From a strict safety point of view (neglecting the fact that `getISync` implies locks), is `getI` immune to thread interference? I mean, is it safe? Does `getISync` offer something more, or is just the same thing in regard of safety? If there's a difference, please explain.

N.B. I know that on `int` fields (in this example), read and write operations are natively considered atomic.

Comment: Did you mean to make `i` volatile? You mention volatility in your title, but ehn nowhere else...

Comment: Write atomicity is nowhere close to all you need to be thread-safe. You need to ensure *visibility* of that write, which is not implied by atomicity.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think `int` is natively volatile. I mentioned it just for the point. Think to be ok (new to concurrency :( ).

Comment: @artaxerxe: No, `int` writes are atomic, but not volatile. They're different concepts.